# How to mock autowired dependencies in Spring Boot MockMvc Unit tests?

Tags: spring-boot, mockito

I am expanding upon the basic Spring Boot examples, adding an "autowired" repository dependency to my controller. I would like to modify the unit tests to inject a Mockito mock for that dependency, but I am not sure how.

I was expecting that I could do something like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = MockServletContext.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
public class ExampleControllerTest {

    private MockMvc mvc;

    @InjectMocks
    ExampleController exampleController;

    @Mock
    ExampleRepository mockExampleRepository;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
      MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    mvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(new ExampleController()).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void getExamples_initially_shouldReturnEmptyList() throws Exception {
        mvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/example").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().string(equalTo("[]")));
    }
}
```

but it doesn't inject the mock into the `MockMvc`. Can anyone explain how to do this with `@Autowired` dependencies, rather than constructor arguments?

Comment: Create a configuration which contains a mock of your beans. Then in your setup reset the mocks. (In Spring Boot 1.4 you will be able to add a `@MockBean` annotation which makes this easier).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please use `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` instead of `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)`
and you have to use the `ExampleController exampleController;` field with the injected mocks instead of creating a new one in line `mvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(new ExampleController()).build();`

Comment: That is interesting. I had not heard of that class. However, it does not appear that this one change results in the mock dependency being autowired

Comment: Please try to use @RunWith(Mockito...) and use in this line `mvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(new ExampleController()).build();` the exampleController with the injected mocks. If you create a new instance of example controller as you do in this line, no auto-wiring will be applied.

Comment: nice. That seems to be the trick. If you get a chance, update your answer to include this additional info, please. And also, thank you for saving me a bunch of time.

Comment: Answer changed, have a nice day.

Comment: Which of them? The one from `org.mockito.junit` or the one from `org.mockito.runners?